# XDSoft Datetimepicker plugin AM PM selection fails

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

XDSoft datetimepicker plugin AM/PM selection fails

Am using the following Plugin :

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

My code is..

```
 jQuery('#txtFrom').datetimepicker({ minDate:0, formatTime:'g:iA', format: 'M d Y g:iA'});
```

The code resulting same result i want i.e May 10 2017 11:00PM
When i click on the same text box again... the time automatically changes to May 10 2017 11:00AM... The PM gets change into AM by itself... i tried reading the content over internet and could not able to solve it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change from:

```
format: 'M d Y g:iA'
```

to:

```
format: 'M d Y h:i A'
```

```js
$('#txtFrom').datetimepicker({
    minDate:0,
    formatTime:'g:iA',
    format: 'M d Y h:i A'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/jquery.datetimepicker.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<form>
    <input type="text" id="txtFrom">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you so much friend. when i tried it instead of am pm it switches the time to reduce by 1hr. So i used the JS & CSS files mentioned in your example instead of the one i was having... it did the magic :) thank you so much :)

Comment: @user2301765 I am also getting the problem that the time reduces by 1 hour. How did you fix it?